# Is there a term for replacing name with a number/code?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

For example instead of using Mrs Johnson to use Subject 2332

Comment: I have come across the term **identity-masking** in some offline articles. It is done to protect the identity of the original author/participant by changing their name or giving them a false identity. This might sound a little computer-ish but I do not have a source for this term.

Comment: It's sometimes called "deidentification".  This is a term often used in medical research.

Comment: It's called imprisoning, from the not-so-famous lead-in to the British television show, *The Prisoner*: "I am not a number! I am a free man!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider using the noun [**code-name**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/code_name) as a verb:

> A name used to clandestinely identify somebody or something, either
>   for military or espionage purposes, or for commercial confidentiality.

Even though the Wiktionary definition has a noun usage only, it is broadly used as a transitive verb.

> I code-named  Mrs Johnson Subject 2332.

Actual usage:

> Edward Arnold ["Eddie" Chapman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddie_Chapman) (16 November 1914 – 11 December 1997)
>   was an English criminal and wartime spy. During the Second World War
>   he offered his services to Nazi Germany as a spy and subsequently
>   became a British double agent. His British Secret Service handlers
>   **codenamed** him Zigzag in acknowledgement of his rather erratic personal
>   history.

[Wikipedia]

Answer (score 1):

Yes: it's *anonymise* (to make anonymous)

> [with object] (usually as adjective *anonymized*)
>   Remove identifying particulars or details from (something, especially medical test results) for statistical or other purposes:
>   *anonymized testing of routine blood samples*
>
> [[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/anonymize?q=anonymise)]

Answer (score 0):

I would use ***[encode](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/encoding)***.

Accordingto Collins:

> ***noun***
>
> 1) the action of transforming a message into code
>       2)(computing) the action of converting (characters and symbols) into a digital form as a series of impulses
>       3)(linguistics) the action of expressing a message in another language

Answer (score 0):

The Social Security Administration calls it "enumeration."  The process of assigning Social Security numbers to individuals' names is called "enumeration."

www.socialsecurity.gov/open/data/Enumeration-Accuracy.html

Example:

Social Security has enumerated Betty Johnson with Social Security number 123-45-6789.

Or more simply:

Social Security has enumerated Betty Johnson 123-45-6789.